# How to wrap Agenda in express apiRoutes in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, agenda

I want to schedule a simple task using Agenda with nodejs, however it is not executing when it is wrapped in apiRoutes (express router)

```
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

apiRoutes.post('/scheduler/submit', function (req, res) {
    agenda.define('test', function () {
         console.log('Test');
    });

    agenda.on('ready', function () {
         agenda.every('*/1 * * * *', 'test');
         agenda.start();
    });
});
```

but if i place that code outside, it works however. Hmm, any idea?

```
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

agenda.define('test', function () {
      console.log('Test');
});

agenda.on('ready', function () {
      agenda.every('*/1 * * * *', 'test');
      agenda.start();
});

apiRoutes.post('/scheduler/submit', function (req, res) {
    // Leave blank
});
```

Comment: Do you want the `agenda` object to run that code forever or only one time when a request is made?

Comment: Just 1 time when a request is made. Is it possible? I try console.log agenda in the request, it print agenda db object correctly, but it does not execute.

Comment: it *should* be. I have a hunch that it involves the `.on` function but I'm looking through their source code to confirm.

Comment: Ok. Once u get the answer don't forget to update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `on` function. When you call the `agenda.on('ready', ...)` in your express code you are adding a listen to the `agenda` emitter's `ready` array but that signal only occurs when `agenda` connects to your database when the server initializes. In other words, after `agenda` connects to your database when the server starts up it will not emit that same signal again which is why the code in your express API isn't executing.

To fix this, I'd recommend you confirm that `agenda` has connected to your database successfully and run the process. If not, then add the `.on('ready', ...)` event listener.

Sample source:

```
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// Use this to determine if a conneciton has been established between agenda
// and the database
var connectionEstablised = false;

// When the connection is established, set the flag
agenda.on('ready', function() {
    connectionEstablished = true;
});

// It's better practice to have this function defined on your agenda object
// When the server initializes rather than having initializing it only if a POST
// request occurrs.
agenda.define('test', function () {
     console.log('Test');
});



apiRoutes.post('/scheduler/submit', function (req, res) {

    // Only execute this code if you can confirm the connection is established
    if (connectionEstablished) {
        agenda.every('*/1 * * * *', 'test');
        agenda.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: you are the saver.